# Open excel and get count of a column in VB script?

Tags: vbscript

I am using Vb Script to open excel and count a number of column in a sheet.

I  am unable to get the count of column A.

This is my script,

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\achidambaram\Desktop\Nikhi\Automate\Text_update.xlsx")

set sh = objWorkbook.sheets("Sheet2")

dim k

k = sh.cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row

msgbox (K)
```

Answer (score 0):

`xlUp` is a constant in VBA, not in VBS. Use its value -4162 instead.

```
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\achidambaram\Desktop\Nikhi\Automate\Text_update.xlsx")
    Dim sh, k
    Set sh = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 
    k = sh.cells(sh.Rows.Count,"A").End(-4162).Row
    MsgBox k
    objWorkbook.Close
```